# Building a Taxable Portfolio Properly

Tags: united-states, taxes, investing, retirement, etf

I'm currently maxing my 401(k) and a Roth IRA. I have emergency savings, savings for a house down payment, and savings for vehicle maintenance. I'm looking for advice on how to properly build a *taxable* portfolio of Vanguard ETFs to supplement my retirement savings.

I've read that total market ETFs are the most tax efficient investment for a taxable portfolio, so I plan to buy 1 share each of VTI and VXUS every two weeks. I chose these ETFS because the Boglehead's wiki's [Lazy Portfolio page](https://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Lazy_portfolios) recommended them, but also because I do not have the required cash to invest in fractional shares of their equivalent mutual funds.

I am 30 years old. When I begin shifting my allocation to include more fixed income products, I will include them in my 401(k) and IRA accounts. Please assume that I will re-balance all of my investments as I build my taxable portfolio (i.e., I will buy fewer equity mutual funds in my tax-protected accounts as I accrue more equity ETFs in my taxable account until I reach the desired allocation across all portfolios).

Please critique this strategy for building a taxable portfolio (e.g., unanticipated tax implications, making purchases too often, etc).

Comment: "I also do not have the required cash to invest in fractional shares of their equivalent mutual funds." VTI has a NAV of about $111$ these days. So what does it mean when you say that you do not have enough money to invest in _fractional_ shares of the near-equivalent mutual fund while you do have enough money to invest in _one_ share on VTI?

Comment: Remember that for most purposes, ETFs and mutual funds are available in all the same flavors and are equivalent to each other. Yes, index funds tend to be more tax-efficient than actively managed funds

Comment: @DilipSarwate: The mutual funds likely have minimum investments.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: BrenBarn is right. The minimum investment for the mutual fund equivalent of VTI is $3000. When I say that I do not have enough money to invest in fractional shares of the near-equivalent mutual fund, I mean that I do not have $3000 and that mutual funds can be purchased in fractions of shares while ETFs must be purchased as whole shares.

Comment: What is your purpose of building this portfolio?  What time frame are you looking at?

Comment: @PeteB. The taxable account is solely to supplement my other retirement accounts, so my time frame is between 20-30 years.

Comment: Your plan sounds good.  You may want to move more to post tax as your plan will likely make you very wealthy.  You may want to do partial retirements or very early retirement.

Comment: Why would you want to have the fixed income products in either of the tax advantaged accounts when those products typically have a lower return over an extended period?

Comment: @homer150mw I think because interest is taxed at a higher rate than dividends and capital gains. Investopedia says: "Fixed-income investments, such as bonds and real estate investment trusts (REITs) generate a regular cash flow. In 2010, these interest payments are subject to the same ordinary income tax rates of up to 35%. A tax-deferred retirement account provides investors with a shelter for this income." If things have changed since 2010, this might not be the best strategy. Have things changed since 2010?

Comment: I'm not sure that they have. You would have to do the math to see what makes the most sense. Without looking at any specific investments you would have to ask yourself if it is better to have a fixed income investment paying say 5% or an equity investment paying 8% in the tax advantaged account. Of course all investments are different but it would be worth looking at the math to see which works or better in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a bad strategy. However:

- Target a % allocation instead of buying 1 share of each. Most efficient frontier portfolios (portfolio with highest expected return per unit of risk) and long term strategic allocations with the highest sharp ratio are ~60-70% U.S. domestic, 20-30% Int'l Developed, and 5-10% Emerging Markets (ticker VWO)
- Vanguard index ETFs are exactly what you want to use
- Personally I would do 70% VTI, 20% VEA (not VXUS), and 10% VWO. At times, due to its excessive risk, i would go to 0% in Emerging Markets, which you wouldn't be able to do with VXUS.

If you REALLY want tax efficiency you can buy stocks that don't pay a dividend, usually growth stocks like FB, GOOGL, and others. This way you will never have to pay any dividend tax - all your tax will be paid when you retire at a theoretically lower tax rate (<--- really a grey tax area here).

*Also, check out Robin Hood. They offer commission free stock trading.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I hadn't thought to break down International Developed and Emerging markets, but I guess more diversification couldn't hurt.